# How do I get my Activity Indicator to start at the right time?

Tags: ios, swift, uiactivityindicatorview

From everything I read you can activate it with with a button so I put it right after the button action that starts the http POST and upload, but right now it starts spinning right after the function has finished, after the upload is complete, the opposite of what I would expect. 
I'm new to Swift so please explain your answer as you would to a nubie. Many thanks.

```
@IBAction func upload(sender: AnyObject) {

    myActivityIndicator.startAnimating()

    var imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(myImageView.image)

    if imageData != nil{
        var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string:"http://www.example.com/upload.php")!)

        var session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

        var boundary = NSString(format: "---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449")
        var contentType = NSString(format: "multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary)
        //  println("Content Type \(contentType)")
        request.addValue(contentType, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

        var body = NSMutableData.alloc()

        // Title
        body.appendData(NSString(format: "\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
        body.appendData(NSString(format:"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"title\"\r\n\r\n").dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
        body.appendData("Hello World".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true)!)

        // Image
        body.appendData(NSString(format: "\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
        body.appendData(NSString(format:"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"profile_img\"; filename=\"img.jpg\"\r\n").dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
        //           println("body=\(body)")
        body.appendData(NSString(format: "Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n").dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
        body.appendData(imageData)
        body.appendData(NSString(format: "\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)



        request.HTTPBody = body


        var returnData = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse: nil, error: nil)

        var returnString = NSString(data: returnData!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

        println("returnString \(returnString)")

        //self.myActivityIndicator.stopAnimating()
        //self.myImageView.image = nil

    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
myActivityIndicator.startAnimating()        
          dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(Int(QOS_CLASS_USER_INITIATED.value), 0)) {
            //Do your post code here or call the post func
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                myActivityIndicator.stopAnimating()
            }
    }
```

http://ijoshsmith.com/2014/07/29/a-swift-app-that-calls-json-web-services/
http://www.raywenderlich.com/79149/grand-central-dispatch-tutorial-swift-part-1

Comment: Awesome, thank you. It took me a moment to figure it out how to add this to the code (function) but it definitely worked. I saw this elsewhere but couldn't figure out how to use it without your help. Here's a tip (more help) for others who also find this useful; after adding this to my function I got a couple of red errors, but code hinting showed me where to add self. to a couple of items, including self.myActivityIndicator,stopAnimating which fixed all the errors.

Comment: You're welcome. I do agree that Woodstock's answer is more comprehensive. He really did a good job explaining the problem and suggesting best practices. Kudos to him

Answer (score 1):

This is occurring because this call is blocking the main thread (which is responsible for updating the UI:

```
var returnData = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse: nil, error: nil)
```

Thus, after this line of code everything you do on the UI will not show up until after this synchronous call has completed.

The solution here is to make this call on a background thread, and then when finished update the UI on the main thread.

One of the nicest ways to achieve this is using GCD (Grand Central Dispatch). GCD is a thread API which makes doing work on a background thread easy peasy.

As already mentioned in the answer above:

```
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_USER_INTERACTIVE, 0), {

        var returnData = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse: nil, error: nil)

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            myActivityIndicator.stopAnimating()
        }

    })
```

**One of the key tenets in iOS development is not blocking the main thread.**

This leads to a bad user experience.

**Furthermore, it's really important to always update the UI on the main thread.**

Just so you know there are other ways to handle this kind of situation without GCD (threading API), **`NSOperation`** for example.

Also, you could send an **asynchronous** request instead.

Comment: Great answer and so much more than just a fix, you make it very understandable why the problem occurred in the first place and how to use best practices. Unfortunately, I can only have one accepted answer and since this comment poses no question or additional information it will likely be deleted, but your answer won't because it provides very useful additional information and that is what is important. I don't even have enough reputation to up the useful number but hopefully someone else will as this will help many I'm sure.

Comment: @RickP my pleasure friend.